# error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type

Tags: c

I am trying the below code in my program and getting the error.

```
abc rec; //abc is a struct which is having data member with void*.

rec.data = (price*)malloc(sizeof(price)); //rec.data is a void* and price is a structure

emp * e = (emp *)calloc(2, sizeof(emp)); // emp is a struct, which is member of struct price.
e[0].a = 1; 
rec.data->emp = e; // error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
```

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. C is **not** C++!

Comment: What do you not understand on such a direct error message?

Comment: @Youka, I don't know about the OP, but *I* don't understand the inherently erroneous message he claims to have received.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The error message makes perfect sense, and is not "erroneous" as you claim. `data` is `void*`, which you shouldn't dereference with `->`.

Comment: @Youka `void *` **is** a pointer to object type, so this error message is bogus.  (C11 6.2.5/19, "The `void` type [...] is an incomplete object type")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is of type `void*`, so `data->emp` would be of type `void`, which you can't really have, much less assign to.

Comment: ANy other way to assign the emp to data?

Comment: @user1138143 `((price*)rec.data)->emp = e`

Comment: Thanks @CoffeeandCode. It works.

Comment: or use an intermediate `price *p;` Its an extra line of code and one helluva lot easier to follow if read by a novice.